# AVFoundation camera zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I use `AVFoundation` framework to display video from camera.

The code how i use it is usual:

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] ;
...   
captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
...
[cameraView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
...
```

So i want to add zoom function to camera.

I have found 2 solutions how to implement zoom.

***First*** : is to use `CGAffineTransform`:

`cameraView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x,y);`

***Second*** :  is to put cameraView in the scroll view ,set up max and min scrolling and set this view as zooming view.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return cameraView;
}
```

What is the best way to make zooming better performance and quality? Are there any else solutions to make zoom? Maybe i missed some `AVFoundation` methods for zooming.

Thank you.

Comment: I was hoping for some comments from a real expert but since no one has chimed in I'd thought I'd share my experience. Since there is no real mechanical zoom, its really just playing with aspect ratios.  I've found when working with layers that using the CGAffineTransform to work very well, especially if you setup your AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity setting when creating your session. linking the transform with a slider or pinch gesture is pretty straight forward.  The transform even handles odd frame sizes for if you set its frame to the views bounds.  hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for some answer, i wanted to implement zooming using transform, but i took really little time to make it using the scrollview zooming, works great:) I thought asking the question maybe AV framework has something for zooming.

Comment: good tip on the scroll view.  I'm going to check that out as well.

Comment: How far does this allow you to zoom out? Can you zoom out past the default level?

Comment: Hi! The iPhone 5 or newer devices with iOS7 is supported  setVideoZoomScale: on the AVCaptureDevice. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799110/apply-cgaffinetransform-prior-to-layer-being-displayed/22834443#22834443

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there is actually a `GCFloat` called `setVideoScaleandCropFactor`.

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I'm not sure if this is just for still image output but I've been working on it and it does well if you set it to a gesture or a slider and let that control the float.

You can find a demo of it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190).

Good stuff. Im trying to loop it so I can create a barcode scanner with a zoom. What im doing is rough though haha.

Comment: videoScaleAndCropFactor doesn't work for video. videoMaxScaleAndCropFactor is set to 1.0 and if you change videoScaleAndCropFactor an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Nathan Kellert i didn't get the AVCaptureSession property  VideoScaleandCropFactor ,,can you plz explain how to implement zooming the video (Not Scale the view of video)... ?

Comment: Video scale and crop factor is the zoom of the actual video itself. Unlike previous methods developers used. Which was 1) capture video 2) scale it 3) recapture video based off new scale(which causes pixelation). The new ios 7 stuff actually zooms in the video first and then captures it at full resolution. You basically want to set a view zoom so that way the viewer can see on the screen the same thing the video is actually capturing. Otherwise the video could be capturing zoomed video but the screen looks completely normal. Really the demo app does a lot to help show how it works.

Comment: Hi! The iPhone 5 or newer devices with iOS7 is supported setVideoZoomScale: on the AVCaptureDevice. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799110/apply-cgaffinetransform-prior-to-layer-being-displayed/22834443#22834443