# iOS zoom (quality + focus) in custom camera app vs iOS 7 native camera app

Tags: ios, performance, zooming, avfoundation, uigesturerecognizer

I am currently using the following code to zoom in and out using the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchToZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        lastScale = 1.0;
    }

    CGFloat currentScale = [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.previewView.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

    // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
    const CGFloat kMaxScale = 4.0;
    const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - gestureRecognizer.scale);
    scale = MIN(scale, kMaxScale/currentScale);
    scale = MAX(scale, kMinScale/currentScale);

    ((AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.previewView.layer).affineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(((AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.previewView.layer).affineTransform,
                                                                                                    scale,
                                                                                                    scale);
    lastScale = gestureRecognizer.scale;
}
```

Two things that are very different and particularly bad:

1. Zoom quality - I am not sure how Apple is doing it but the zoom quality is better in the native app and I am wondering if there is a way to solve this issue.
2. Focus - Another issue is focus. Objects are better focused in the native camera app as compared to the custom app.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS7, you should use the new camera API like

> [setVideoZoomFactor](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW111):

and others.

Example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799110/apply-cgaffinetransform-prior-to-layer-being-displayed/22834443#22834443).